# How to avoid that CR13 change the file encoding of my VS2012 project?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

Last week I upgrated a big project from Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2012, everything worked perfectly, even the reports that where made with Crystal Reports 10 (the Dev edition that came with VS2005).

I just installed RC13 so I can edit RPT files in VS2012, but the first time I opened the project I got a message telling me that I should "upgrade" my project to the current version of CR, so I did it.

The problem is that it "touched" every single code file (all X.vb files), and now those files don't compile if they have variable names with "ñ" (ASCII 164): I have a lot of variables like `TamañoPagina` and `FechaMañana` (I speak spanish), and I can't go throught 1500 files changing variable names.

I can work with a backup I did right before the CR upgrade, but I ask me every time I open it.

My question is: how can I prevent that CR13 change the file encoding (I suppose) of the files in my VS2012 proyect? or avoid that mesage every time I open the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found out what caused the problem: The problem wasn't in the *.vb files, but a single change in the web.config. CR13 changed this:

```
<globalization culture="en-US"/>
```

To this:

```
<globalization culture="en-US" fileEncoding="utf-8"/>
```

That new attribute (somehow) was the culprit that the compiler won't recognize the "ñ" character in variable names.

So, the procedure is to upgrade the proyect to RC13 (as asked when opening the proyect) and then remove the `FileEncoding` attribute if it where added.